# Doesn't work horizontal form

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to use the bootstrap and make a horizontal form. Unfortunately, my form generates a normal, normal one. As if `form-horizontal` does not work (blocks are generated from ReactJS).

```
<div id="app" class="container">
<block>
    <block>
        <div class="row">
            <header class="col-sm-12 header">
                <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase header__title">formularz wprowadzania danych osobowych!</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <block>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">Imie: </label>
                    <div class="inputs col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Nazwisko: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="dalej">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </block>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dropped the `.form-horizontal` class requirement.
- `.form-group` no longer applies styles from the `.row` via mixin, so `.row`
  is now required for horizontal grid layouts (e.g., `<div class="form-group row">`).
- Added new `.col-form-label` class to vertically center labels with
  `.form-controls`.
- Added new `.form-row` for compact form layouts with the grid classes
  (swap your `.row` for a `.form-row` and go).

[Bootstrap 4 Forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#forms-1)

Comment: Lol, strange. Thanks